# Are the ordination-statuses in this list exclusive and comprehensive?

Tags: church-of-england, ordination, lay-ministry, church-offices

I'm constructing a survey of Anglican worshippers in England. One of the questions asks about *ordination-status*, with the following options:

- I am ordained
- I am a curate
- I am a licensed lay-person
- I am an unlicensed lay-person

For worshippers in the Church of England, are these categories:

- **comprehensive** (*everyone* is described by *one* of them)
- **exclusive** (*no-one* is described by *two* of them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is not exclusive - curates are ordained. (Did you mean, ordinand - someone who is training for ordination?).

Also there are [several statuses](https://www.churchofengland.org/life-events/vocations/exploring-lay-ministry) for lay people who are not ordained:

- licensed lay minister - someone who's not ordained but has a leadership role in a church.
- recognised
- authorised

Depending on what your purpose is, you could simply ask whether someone has an official (non-ordained) role in the church, or break it down into those groups. Either way I think you need some explanation for what you're asking.